# for j in range(len(columns)): TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Tags: python

```
for i in range(len(rows)):
    columns = rows[i].find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="td")
    for j in range(len(columns)):
        if columns[j].text == "JKL":
            columns[0].click()
```

What is the problem of my code?

Comment: No idea. This isn't a [MRE], so it's impossible to test it or to know much about it at all, really.

Comment: can you try printing columns after it is defined and pasting that in your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Before starting to answer this, we'd need to know what library(s) you're using. You can [edit] to clarify. Please make a [mre], and clarify what your question is exactly; like, were you expecting a `WebElement` to *have* a `len()`, or were you not expecting a `WebElement` object in the first place? For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue, in this line `columns = rows[i].find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="td")` you're only getting one element so it can't loop through it. Essentially it's saying columns = one column element with these attributes. `.find_element()` is the issue since it only finds one element.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error is that `find_element()` is returning a `WebElements` type.  `len()` generally doesn't work on a webelement so you get an error.

If you were trying to create a list of rows which have the `<td>` tag then you would start by declaring the list as `columns = []` just before the `for i` loop.  The line to build the list would look like this:

```
columns.append(rows[i].find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="td"))
```

which would give you a list of webelements.

That nested `for j` loop is probably not necessary; you can probably just compare each tag as you extract it from `rows`, but I think that `find_element()` is going to throw an exception on every line which does not have the tag.  I'm guessing that you should probably be looking for an `<a>` tag rather than `<td>`.  I don't have enough experience with Selenium to speak more competently, but I suspect that you're probably looking for something more along the lines of this:

```
for i in range(len(rows)):
    try:
        column = rows[i].find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="td")
    except NoSuchElement:
        #we expect this exception; do nothing
        pass
    else:
        if column.text == "JKL":
            column.click()
            break
```

The `break` should get you out of the `for` loop.